# Update unique value (String) for each insert when doing multiple insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert, unique-key

I am performing insert operation like follow on Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio:

```
INSERT INTO contact (scode, slastname, sfirstname)
    (SELECT     
         ******,
         t.slastname,
         t.sfirstname
     FROM   
         table1 t
     WHERE  
         t.slastname NOT IN (SELECT slastname FROM contact)
         AND t.slastname <> '' 
         AND t.istatus IN (0, 3, 4))
```

This insert is supposed to make few hundreds of insert.

But here I want to insert `scode` like `C000512`, `C000513`, `C000514` ....

and `C000511` being the latest scode entry previously present in contacts.

How do I make this `SCODE` insert unique for each insert?

Previously I have tried

```
(select substring((select max(scode) from contact), 0, 5) + '0' + 
     cast(cast(substring((select max(scode) from contact),4,8) as
int)+ 1 as varchar))
```

or:

```
(SELECT Substring((SELECT Max(scode) FROM contact), 1, 5)
    + CONVERT(VARCHAR, Substring((SELECT Max(scode) FROM contact), 4, 8) + 1, 101)),
```

Or also by creating a variable. But `SCODE` wasn't updating.

Any suggestions how I can make this work?

Comment: I suggest making use of the `row_number()` function to help you generate a unique number per row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it into a transaction, row_number new rows.

```
begin tran;
with mx as(
   select cast(substring(max(scode), 2, 7) as 
int) n 
   from contact)
INSERT INTO contact (scode, slastname, sfirstname)
SELECT     
         'C'+ right('000000' + cast(mx.n + row_number() over(order by (select null)) as varchar(6)), 6) ,
         t.slastname,
         t.sfirstname
     FROM   
         table1 t
         cross join mx
     WHERE  
         t.slastname NOT IN (SELECT slastname FROM contact)
         AND t.slastname <> '' 
         AND t.istatus IN (0, 3, 4);
  commit tran;
```

Answer (score 2):

The best solution - I think - would be to use

- an `ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)` column to get SQL Server to handle the automatic increment of your numeric value
- a **computed, persisted** column to convert that numeric value to the value you need

So try this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Contact
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    SCODE AS 'C' + RIGHT('000000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(6)), 6) PERSISTED,
    sLastName VARCHAR(100),
    sFirstName VARCHAR(100)
    -- your other columns here
  )
```

Now, every time you insert a row into `Contact` **without** specifying values for `ID` or `SCODE`:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Contact(sLastName, sFirstName, ......)
VALUES ('Doe', 'John', ......)
```

then SQL Server will **automatically** increase your `ID` value, and `SCODE` will contain values like `C000512`, `C000513`,...... and so on - automatically, safely, reliably, no duplicates.

Comment: It's good solution but these tables are predefined in our company's system so can't change them. Is there any way I can do this with loops and variables?

Comment: The only *other* viable solution is using a `SEQUENCE` (instead of the `IDENTITY` column) to deal with this. Loops and variables aren't the way to go